# Why don't tag synonyms work for "Ignored Tags"?

Tags: support, ignored-tags

Tag [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) has a synonym: [winform](/questions/tagged/winform).

I added `winform` to my *Ignored Tags* list, but it doesn't filter question with [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the tag [winform](/questions/tagged/winform) doesn't exist. The word "winform" is effectively a pointer to [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) and when a post is made, it is only tagged with [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms).

You can, however, use wildcards to catch multiple possible forms of a word: ignore `winform*` and it should catch anything that starts with "winform". Without a wildcard, the matches are exact.

Comment: So this means the tag ignoring system is based on the name of the tag using a String and not an ID to the tag itself?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Yes, it's primarily just a client-side filtering based on a regex.